# Does TUniQuery support simultaneous Requests

Tags: delphi, postgresql

i want to ask this question ( as it's so important at least for me ) :

I use a TUniQuery component ( from the the [UniDAC](http://www.devart.com/unidac/components.html) ) in my project with a PostgreSQL Database , so let's suppose this : 
there are 10 users trying to Register or Logging at the same time , will the TUniQuery handle all these 10 simultaneous ( Register or logging ) Requests at the same time ? or what will happen please .

many thanks

Comment: Your project is programmed by IntraWeb ?

Comment: If you are writing a server application that clients will connect to, you'll need to use multiple threads to handle multiple connections. The UniDAC documentation or samples should have information on using the database in multi-threaded applications. If your question is about something else entirely, please [edit] to make it more clear what you're asking.

Comment: many thanks Ken , yes i'm using a server / client App , and i've read the UniDAC Help doc , so maybe i will refer to using the Pooling Property , will this be helpful ?

Comment: Normally, when you have one Session opened with Postgresql only one statement can be executed concurrently. In your case if you use within a request-response cycle one connection from the pool you will be fine. But do not try to reuse the same connection, always create a new connection to the database at the beginning of the request-responce cycle (please refer to documentation about details).